# F# AsyncSeq- How do a mke asyncSeq Iterate in the order values are returned?

Tags: asynchronous, f#, sequence

I am having some trouble with an AsyncSeq that runs some tasks in parallel and then iterates the results of those parallel tasks only ever doing one at a time. I would think this should be perfect for AsyncSeq however because it iterates in the initial order of the sequence it will not do the tasks as they come in.
Difficult to explain. Probably easy to just look at this little mockup:

```
    //completes after the given time
    let randomwait time=
        async{
            printfn "started waiting : %i"time
            do! Async.Sleep(time*1000);
            printfn "waited %i" time
            return time
        }
    //Creates 10 tasks in decending order of time taken to complete: 10s,9s 8s, etc
    let stream=
        asyncSeq{
            for i=10 downto 1 do
                let waitTime= i
                yield randomwait waitTime
        }
    let run =
            
        let task=
            stream 
               |> AsyncSeq.mapAsyncParallel id // This runs all our randomWait tasks at once
               |>AsyncSeq. 1(fun time ->async{ printfn "printing for time : %i" time})
        Async.RunSynchronously task
```

I want the code to output the following with a one second delay in between each print.

```
Printing for Time: 1
Printing for Time: 2
etc etc
```

However because the order of iteration is not set by the order of completion in the previous parallel task the results are backwards, and are all printed at once after the first 10 second task has completed.

```
Printing for Time: 10
Printing for Time: 9
etc etc
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. I'm happy to use other solutions if necessary, anything that allows parallel then one at a time iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key operation that matters in your code is `mapAsyncParallel`. This iterates over the input asynchronous sequence, starts all tasks and then yields the results in the order in which they were started.

The operation does not wait for all tasks to complete, but it only yields the result of Nth task once it yielded results of all N-1 earlier tasks.

The following sample stream demonstrates the behaviour better than your example:

```
let stream=
    asyncSeq { 
        for waitTime = 5 downto 1 do
            yield randomwait waitTime
        for waitTime = 10 to 15 do
            yield randomwait waitTime
    }
```

If you use this as a sample, your code will wait 5 seconds, then it will print "printing for time" 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 (because it had to wait 5 seconds until the first task completes and in the meantime, the remaining 4 completed), but then it will wait 5 more seconds and print "printing for time" 6, wait 1 sec, print 7, wait 1 sec, print 8 etc.

If you replace `mapAsyncParalle` with just `mapAsync`, then the code will run the tasks in sequence and wait (sequentially) for each task to complete. Then you will have nothing happening in parallel and the waiting times will be longer.

To do what (I think) you want, the best option would be to switch from using `AsyncSeq<T>` to using `Observable<T>`. Asynchronous sequences are sequential and preserve order of elements. Observable does not do this. Using the [FSharp.Control.Reactive](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Control.Reactive/reference/fsharp-control-reactive-observablemodule.html) library, you can do:

```
let task=
    stream 
    |> AsyncSeq.toObservable
    |> Observable.bind Observable.ofAsync 
    |> Observable.iter (fun time -> printfn "printing for time : %i" time)

Observable.wait task |> ignore
```

Here, the `bind` operation takes an observable, for each produced value, it starts a new observable (in our case, it only produces one result), but then it collects all the results in the order in which they arrive, so you get the result for `1` first, even though this was started as the fifth element.

Comment: Thanks heaps, I will test this tomorrow. I had experimented with observables but I really struggled to figure out how they should interop with asycseq. That and just how insanely many slight arcane seeming functions existed in the observable module.

Comment: I can relate to this! I really like async sequences, because they are logically quite simple (sequential but asynchronous). Observables are push-based (non-sequential), which makes the whole logic more tricky. But in this case, the `Observable.bind` does exactly what you need (I think).

Comment: Converting from AsyncSeq to Observable is easy, but going the other way round is tricky (because observable may produce more things than the consumer of AsyncSeq wants to process - so either you lose data or you need a buffer).

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou very much Tomas Petricek.
This is my final result:

```
let observables= schedulesGrouped|>List.map(fun (schedules,groupName)->
            printfn "Setting up observables for group: %s" groupName
            schedules
                |>AsyncSeq.toObservable
                |>Observable.bind Observable.ofAsync
                |>Observable.iter(fun transferTask ->
                    Async.Start( processTask groupName transferTask))

            )
        let outPut=observables|>Observable.mergeSeq
        outPut|>Observable.wait
```

Some adjustments to your original idea were made because i wanted to run a task that is partially asynchronous in the iteration but it is essentially still the same.

Thanks heaps for your help.